# external pendrive is read only

Tags: macos, external-disk

When i plug my external pen-drive(FAT32) in macbook pro(OS: Mojave) it is getting detected but nothing can be copied on pendrive. 
Seems like there has been some restriction on my office mac so that pendrive remain read only.

Need help in removing read only protection from pendrive.

PS: This problem can be solved by changing registry in Windows but dont know  how to remove it on mac.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's FAT32, and not NTFS? MacOS can read NTFS but not write to it natively.

If you can't write to a USB drive formatted as HFS+ (Mac's native format), ***then*** I would agree that your office had put some block in place. How to over-ride that may not be easy or possible, depending on how they have implemented and what level of access you have on the computer.

Comment: I am pretty sure that its FAT32. in windows by changing registry (setting StorageDevicePolicies = 0) solve the same problem in windows but dont know how in mac.

Comment: If a company has locked down your Mac in this way, then it's unlikely that you would have admin privileges to make changes. There is no magic switch that you can easily flip. They may have installed third-party software: you would need to know what that was and delete it (if you have permissions). It can be done with Mac Profile Manager, but again, you'd have to install that.

Comment: I am admin on my mac...

Comment: That registry key is commonly used for Group Policies, which are imposed security restrictions of Active Directory. In order to do this on a Mac you would need a similar device management solution or the system to be set up that way at the outset. Also if they activated the Root account and changed the password there are still things you will be locked out of even as an admin.